# Quickly turning off and turning on a notebook touchpad

Tags: laptop, drivers, mouse, touchpad, acer-aspire

Is there a way I can easily and quickly turn on / off a notebook touchpad? I have a convenient keyboard on my laptop and a big touchpad right under it and when you type you can accidentally touch the touchpad which causes random text selection/deletion and so on.

The laptop is Acer Aspire E-15 E5-576G-35Z3. I tried to download the Synaptics touchpad driver for this laptop but the official Acer website doesn't provide it and the Synaptics website says that a vendor should provide you with the touchpad drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to disable the touch pad on a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/13803/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-the-touch-pad-on-a-laptop)

Comment: Don't you have a shortcut to disable the touchpad on your keyboard?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Seems I don't have it. On my laptop at the home, there is a special little pit, double tap on that disables a touchpad for some time. But I don't see something similar on this one. How might this thing look?

Comment: Looking at some pictures of the keyboard can you please try Fn+F7?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Awesome! Exactly what was needed! Please post the answer and I'll accept it with my biggest pleasure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at some pictures of the keyboard I found a symbol referring to the touchpad which is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. (the image is from the International keyboard but the <kbd>Fn</kbd> hotkeys are the same in the Russian keyboard).

That should disable the touchpad.

[image]